# Need to perform topic modelling and output the results to a csv sheet

Tags: python, modeling, nmf

I have the following code for topic modeling and I need to take in text data from a CSV file and groups them into 2 topics named Topic 0 and Topic 1:

```
Input: Website name, Text

Output: Website name, Text, Topic
```

---

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF, LatentDirichletAllocation
import numpy as np

def display_topics(H, W, feature_names, documents, no_top_words, no_top_documents):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(H):
        print "Topic %d:" % (topic_idx)
        print " ".join([feature_names[i]
                        for i in topic.argsort()[:-no_top_words - 1:-1]])
        top_doc_indices = np.argsort( W[:,topic_idx] )[::-1][0:no_top_documents]
        for doc_index in top_doc_indices:
            print documents[doc_index]

documents=[//data belonging to "Text" column from csv file goes in here// ] 

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, stop_words='english')
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
tfidf_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

nmf_model = NMF(n_components=no_topics, random_state=1, alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5, init='nndsvd').fit(tfidf)
nmf_W = nmf_model.transform(tfidf)
nmf_H = nmf_model.components_

no_top_words = 2
no_top_documents = 4
display_topics(nmf_H, nmf_W, tfidf_feature_names, documents, no_top_words, no_top_documents)
```

---

Example:

Input:

```
Website name     Text
------------------------------
www.xyz.com      I eat bananas
www.abc.com      I eat apples
www.123.com      I drive a bike
www.abx.com      I drive a car
```

Output:

```
Website name     Text               Topic
--------------------------------------------
www.xyz.com      I eat bananas      Topic 0
www.abc.com      I eat apples       Topic 0
www.123.com      I drive a bike     Topic 1
www.abx.com      I drive a car      Topic 1
```

Comment: on witch criteria you assign topic 0 and topic 1 exactly ? It looks like first half should be topic 0, and second half should be topic 1, right ?

Comment: I am relying on nmf model to do the classification but my challenge is to read the input from 2 different columns i.e the website and its respective text and the model will group the websites into 2 topics based on the text